# Unexpected data storage from AdMob.

Tags: java, android, memory, admob, storage

I have added admob ads to my app. After it, my app's size is increasing. I've checked it in Settings-App-MyApp (Storage data, not cache). I am worrying, will be it increasing until the phone won't has free memory or this size has the limit (how big)?

**Edit:**

```
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Display;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.os.Build;

    public class Failed extends Activity {


        LinearLayout myL;
        Button mB;
        int checker=0;
        int modeChecker=0;
        int level=0;
        AdView adView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                    setContentView(R.layout.failed);
                    myL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutFail);

                    adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

                    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
                    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
                    int screenheight = display.getHeight();

                    if(screenheight>400){
                        myL.setPadding(0, 50, 0, 0);
                    }
                    if(screenheight>800){
                        myL.setPadding(0, 100, 0, 0);
                    }
                     if(screenheight>1000){
                        myL.setPadding(0, 250, 0, 0);
                    }


                checker =  getIntent().getExtras().getInt("type");
                modeChecker = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("modeCheck");
                level = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("level");

        }


        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
        }
        public void tryAgain(View v){
            if(level==1){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Failed.this,FruitTwoTwo.class);
            intent.putExtra("check", checker);
            intent.putExtra("modeCheck", modeChecker);
            startActivity(intent);
            }

            if(level==2){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Failed.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("check", checker);
                intent.putExtra("modeCheck", modeChecker);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            if(level==3){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Failed.this,FourFour.class);
                intent.putExtra("check", checker);
                intent.putExtra("modeCheck", modeChecker);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            if(level==4){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Failed.this,FourFive.class);
                intent.putExtra("check", checker);
                intent.putExtra("modeCheck", modeChecker);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            if(level==5){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Failed.this,MainActivityPlus.class);
                intent.putExtra("check", checker);
                intent.putExtra("modeCheck", modeChecker);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            if(level==6){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Failed.this,SixSix.class);
                intent.putExtra("check", checker);
                intent.putExtra("modeCheck", modeChecker);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            if(level==7){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Failed.this,SevenSix.class);
                intent.putExtra("check", checker);
                intent.putExtra("modeCheck", modeChecker);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            if(level==8){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Failed.this,SevenE.class);
                intent.putExtra("check", checker);
                intent.putExtra("modeCheck", modeChecker);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            if(level==9){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Failed.this,EightE.class);
                intent.putExtra("check", checker);
                intent.putExtra("modeCheck", modeChecker);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            finish();
            adView.destroy();
        }

        public void goBack(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Failed.this,MenuActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("type", checker);
            startActivity(intent);
            adView.destroy();
            finish();
        }
@Override
      public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.resume();
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onPause() {
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
      }

      /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        // Destroy the AdView.
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
      }
}
```

And xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.testlogo.MyDialog"
    android:background="@drawable/greenbackt"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layoutFail"
     >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/failLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/failed"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/fail"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:onClick="tryAgain"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/tryagain"
    android:background="@drawable/button" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/line" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:text="@string/back"
    android:onClick="goBack"
    android:background="@drawable/button" />



  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
                        android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="here is my adUnitId"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Data storage is rising, it's no depends on what is in activity. If activity has AdMob ad and internet connection is on, then data storage will be rising. The indentical activity without AdMob ad will not. 
PS. I am using Nexus 7 2013

Answer (score 0):

Admob will consume small amount of space as it uses a WebView which constructs a database. It will also cache ad resource. But it won't be much (I'd be surprised if it more than 1MB).

Comment: I'am testing now, data storage rised by 1,46 mb :\ and keep raising

Comment: That doesn't sound the amount of storage used by Admob. What other data are you storing or caching in your app? Are you using WebViews elsewhere in your app?

Comment: No, only admob. Also I am using SharedPreferences, but 100% it is not the problem. Data storage is rising when internet is on and ad is refreshing. Some my activities do not destroy ad when activity is finishing. Should I use .destroy() on adview?

Comment: Yes - see https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play

Comment: It didn't help =[ Data storage rised to 3.88mb and keep rising. I don't really know why it happens... Maybe somehow it is possible to delete this database? Like I am deleting SharedPreferences  File file= new File("/data/data/com.example.testlogo/shared_prefs/LevelOne.xml"); 
           file.delete();

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. 3.8MB is not very much so I wouldn't be too concerned. But I really doubt that this is Admob. I think you have something else going on in your app.

Comment: I am sure that it is AdMob. Because without internet connection my app do not store additional data. I do not have any other webview and I have very similiar activity without AdMob ad, but running this activity the size of my app is not rising.

Comment: Show your code, it must be something strange that your are doing. I have many apps using Admob ad I have never had it consume over 500KB.

Comment: I have same problem also, also pretty sure it is by AdMob. I can rotate my screen, and reload the AD, after AD reload, many times later, I saw the size increasing to huge. Also I called adView.destroy() in activity's onDestroy() method. If I rotate the screen without network, the size doesn't increase. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I have same problem and also destroyed adviews. now it uses about 650 kb and it's rising.

Comment: my cache rised to 2.5mb and still rising. could anybody fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

when use the admob,it save some file(cookies,index etc) under Android/yourfile/app_webview. if you dont want increase your data usage, you can delete the file before exit your app.